# Does any mouse really have 11 buttons?

Tags: macos, mouse, mission-control

I have been an OSX user for long, and today while using a scroll mouse I realized in Mission Control it gives us option to choose from Secondary Mouse Button to Mouse Button 11.

If I press the scroll wheel then it is the 3rd button of the mouse. I wonder which mouse or has more than four buttons.

[image]

Comment: Note that things like scroll wheels already count as two buttons, and even so basic mice as the logitech rx1000 has 8 (from the perspective of the driver/gui system).

Comment: My mouse, Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 7000, scroll wheel can actually be gently pressed left/right to scroll down/up a web page at an acceptable pace. I've never looked into changing the speed because I've found it adequate.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: as three buttons, actually. Some also recognize left/right movements so they can count as five alone.

Comment: @progo: which is the reason the mentioned logitech counts as 8. But there are still some mice around which have a mousewheel which can not click. I think, everything you can imagine exists on the  market, plus some.

Comment: I'm now closing this as everybody seems to add their favorite multi-button mouse. It *should* have been quite [easy to find mice with multiple buttons](https://www.google.com/search?q=mouse+with+multiple+buttons).

Comment: @slhck: really sad. I have been user of stackoverflow with hood reps, seen and voted to close many questions. But this is really strange that due to spam like answers this question is closed.

Comment: You were asking which mouse has more than four buttons, which means that there are as many answers as mice, theoretically. We close questions when they attract too many or too opinionated answers, which is the case here. There was no spam – people were just answering the question. Per [ask] we require a bit of research effort which should have found you an answer quite fast.

Answer (score 15):

They certainly exist. And even 11 buttons isn't the maximum that are sold.

Look at the [Razer Naga with 17 buttons](http://www.xoxide.com/razer-naga-mmo-mouse.html) for example.

[image]

Comment: That is a great innovation!!! I guess soon mouse will be obsolete and we will use our **100+ buttons keyboard as mouse**. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya and yet I can't find a reason to need more than about 5 buttons. But then again, if you are using something like PhotoShop, gaming, or CAD you might want some extra macros or hot keys.

Comment: @AthomSfere: This mouse specifically is designed for MMOs, I believe, where that many bindings would be useful. Certainly there are other scenarios where 12 common actions exist, though.

Comment: @Phoshi, Indeed, pretty much all of the Razer brand hardware is aimed at PC gaming. While most mice these days have LMB, CMB/wheel, RMB, and many have two more buttons to function as forward/back, Razer's products come with many additional programmable buttons. (Both their mice and keyboard have them.) Razer isn't the only company to produce things like this, but they are possibly the most famous for it.

Comment: @AthomSfere action RPGs too.  I bought one for playing Path of Exile and bound commands to 10 of the 12 side buttons; unfortunately it's a relatively short mouse and after a few nights of use I discovered the back 6 buttons required bending my thumb too sharply to use and was causing RSI type pain in my thumb.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Ha! That reminds me of a fake April Fool's advertisement in Byte magazine from the early days of desktop computing. It advertised a 104-button mouse, accompanied by a photo of a keyboard mounted on furniture casters. :^)

Answer (score 3):

There is. It's used for gaming, fast editing text and more. For example you can assign all keys to bold, italic or underlined text etc. It could bring you good productivity.

[Anker 5000 DPI Precision Laser Gaming Mouse](http://www.ianker.com/support-c23-g224.html) is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Several gaming mice have 11 buttons:

- [World of Warcraft  Wireless MMO Gaming Mouse](http://steelseries.com/products/games/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-wireless-mmo-gaming-mouse#specifications)
- [Anker 5000 DPI Precision Laser Gaming Mouse](http://www.ianker.com/support-c23-g224.html)

and several models have 10 (e.g., Sensei Wireless Gaming Mouse, Logitec G500)

Comment: I am not much into hardware and gamings... so I wasn't knowing this. +1 for your help. Does multibutton mouse allows us to all sort of things other than games?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Yeah, you can setup macros for common actions with most of them.  Things like shortcuts for `Ctrl+X`, `Ctrl+Z`, etc.  Usually those are determined by what tasks you are doing (text editing would probably want copy/paste, photo editing may want shortcuts to tools, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is that not all 'buttons' are actual buttons. Instead, all mouse actions - including scrolling up and scrolling down - are seen by the computer as buttons. Thus, a standard mouse nowadays (which comes with left/right buttons and a clickable scroll wheel) already has five buttons.

Along those same lines, certain mice have scroll wheels which can be pressed to the left and two the right, which makes a single physical controller be in charge of *five* logical buttons.

[image]

Comment: That button in the center doesn't count though, it just switches scrolling behavior and is never seen by the OS.

Comment: Yes, that is correct but it is not relevant in any way. That particular mouse has nine logical buttons: the standard left and right, two thumb buttons, and the five controlled by the scroll wheel (up-down and left-right scroll, and middle click). The button below the scroll wheel is indeed never seen by the OS. In any case, the scroll wheel controls over half of the logical buttons on the mouse.

Comment: Right, just mentioning that the most prominent "button" in the picture isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

4-6 buttons are pretty common. (Extra side buttons operated by the thumb.)

Gaming mice and special mice/track-balls/3D controllers for CAD purposes can have many more.

The buttons are not necessarily on the mouse itself. I have also seen some (mainly track-balls and 3D-controllers) that had a separate button-pad.

Answer (score 0):

[MMO 7 from Cyborg](http://www.cyborggaming.com/prod/mmo.htm) has 15, yet they are not usable without the driver afaik

[image]

Comment: That looks _exceptionally_ uncomfortable to use...

Comment: as a prowd owner of one i can say: with an optional pinky grip, it is nice to hold, also the length can be customized for bigger hands, and all buttons are pretty ergonomically located (and those small orange ones beside the scroll wheel are real time saver)

Comment: That thing looks about as intuitive and RSI inducing as emacs.